# Does CQEngine support transactional update?

Tags: java, cqengine

I wish to have a queryable on-heap mirror of some underlying resource. When using [CQEngine](https://github.com/npgall/cqengine) to index a class not under our control (*), how can we implement a transactional update (what's the point of all this concurrency if readers *lose* data because of the remove+add semantics!).

(*) `TransactionalIndexedCollection` insists on mauling the type's `equals` method so that equivalent objects are no longer `equals()`!

Also, the provided `equals` method covers "all fields" not "pk fields" so causes duplicates. How do I create an atomically updateable collection with my own PK?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [TransactionalIndexedCollection](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?http://raw.githubusercontent.com/npgall/cqengine/master/documentation/javadoc/apidocs/com/googlecode/cqengine/TransactionalIndexedCollection.html) for atomic updates, you will have to follow its guidance on how to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` on the objects you will store in it.

However, you don't need to store the objects you don't control directly in the indexed collection. For example you could write a wrapper object which you will store in the collection - and this will implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` per the guidance. This way you won't need to modify the objects you don't control.

You can write your attributes so that given a wrapper object, they actually read the fields or call the getter methods from the inner object.

Comment: Hi. I have read and experimented quite a lot before posting and do respect it's all well documented what it does and doesn't do. Thought SO might get your attention (-1 :)) !  I didn't go with the wrapper object as it feels like exactly the kind of work CQE should have taken off my hands. I have dozens of very wide and changeable objects that would need wrapping (proxying?) so this doesn't feel scalable or supportable.
I'm currently using a StampedLock to totally redo queries if an update (not solo add() or remove()) occurs.